# Error in Echo of awk command piped to wc -l

Tags: bash, awk, pipe

I have hundreds of files containing lines similar to this:

```
>34764998   Halalkalicoccus_jeotgali_B3   -132.6938   Halalkalicoccus   0.528  Halobacteriaceae  0.638 Halobacteriales   0.648 Halobacteria   0.706 Euryarchaeota  0.850
```

I am interested in counting the number of items in column 5 that is less than 0.1, ...0.95. I have written a bash script that calls an AWK command to look evaluate the column value then pipe it into wc -l (see below). However, I don't quite have my $, ', and brackets arranged correctly. Can anyone advise me as to what I did incorrectly? This is probably not the most efficient way so I welcome suggestions, but I do want to know what I did wrong with the code I listed.

```
for fileName in 4440319.3_genus.txt 4440372.3_genus.txt 4440373.3_genus.txt 4440378.3_genus.txt 4440379.3_genus.txt 4440380.3_genus.txt 4440381.3_genus.txt
do
   echo $fileName
   for number in 0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4 0.5 0.6 0.7 0.8 0.9 0.95
   do  
      #NUM={awk '$5 < '$number' {print $5}' $filename | wc -l}
      NUM={awk '$5 < $number {print $5}' $filename | wc -l} 
      #NUM=${awk '$5 < '$number' {print $5}' $filename | wc -l}
      #NUM=${awk '$5 < $number {print $5}' $filename | wc -l}
      echo $NUM
   done
done
exit 0
```

All variations yield invalid option errors depending on which line is un-commented.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you're using `sh` or `bash`, here's what I'd do:

```
NUM=`awk -v x=$number '$5 < x {print $5}' $fileName | wc -l`
```

Some explanation why this works and your attempts do not work:

1. You need to execute the pipe and store its **output** in variable `NUM`.  That's why you need the backquotes around the pipe.
2. Your `$number` is a shell variable.  Shell variable expansion does not take place inside single quotes, so your `$number` in the `awk` script has no chance of being substituted with the numbers that you want.  To deal with this, you can either use double quotes to embed the number in the right place (this will cause some trouble because of the other dollar signs in the `awk` script that you don't want to be shell expanded), or you can use an `awk` variable that is externally initialized.  That's what the `-v` argument does.
3. Last but not least, you need to fix the lowercase 'N' in `filename`.

Comment: AHHH! yes, in addition to the -v and x= stuff, I always forget that it is `, not '. Thank you very much @nickie. Works perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

you don't need the `wc -l` pipe, even don't need the for loop of filename, try this:

```
awk -v n=0.95 '$5<n{a++}END{print a}' *_genus.txt
```

Comment: @nickie has a solution that worked, but I am curious about yours, I am running it and I receive one value rather than 40 values. What am I missing?

Comment: Have you removed the `wc -l`?

Comment: @cer the line in answer will print the total count of lines in all your `*_gen...txt` files with `$5<0.95` If you want to get the line count of different `n` say, 0.1, 0.2 .... you could use your shell script, you can also build an awk array. You didn't give the expected output, so I didn't give more codes. there would be questions to your requirements.

Comment: What @Kent would probably want to suggest is that you replace your whole shell script with: `for number in 0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4 0.5 0.6 0.7 0.8 0.9 0.95; do awk -v n=$number 'BEGIN{a=0} $5<n {a++} END {print a}' *_genus.txt; done`.  This should work but it would sum up the counters over all your files.  Mind the `BEGIN` initializing `a`; this is needed if you want zeroes to appear.

Comment: @nickie yes, that is what I meant. also awk array may be better. also if he wants to get those counts per file, awk can handle it too, there is builtin Var: FILENAME, and argument idx etc we could use. but I don't know the exact requirement. since your solution has already solved his problem, it's fine. P.S. I said awk array is better because, say there are 500 files, and 10 ranges we want to count, with the two loops, we have to for each file parsing 10 times. with awk array, we could process once per file.

Comment: I need to print out the NUM s.t. I can keep track of how much is being excluded/included and I failed to mention that in my post. Apologies for not being more thorough. Thank you @Kent and at*nickie for your time and assistance.

Comment: @cer see my comment above yours. I explained shortly how to do it with awk, and trying to gain better performance, if it is a matter of your task.

Answer (score 0):

Here I give the full script:

```
for fileName in 4440319.3_genus.txt 4440372.3_genus.txt 4440373.3_genus.txt 4440378.3_genus.txt 4440379.3_genus.txt 4440380.3_genus.txt 4440381.3_genus.txt
do
   echo $fileName
   for number in 0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4 0.5 0.6 0.7 0.8 0.9 0.95
   do  
      NUM={awk -v n=$number '$5<n{a++}END{print a}'} 
      echo "$NUM records is less than $number"
   done
done
exit 0
```